# Drupal multilingual

Tags: drupal, multilingual

Apart from the module of i18n, is there any other module to build a multilingual site with Drupal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use the many i18n-based modules, Drupal 6 already ships with [Locale](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/locale) and [Content Translation](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/translation), however this can get cucumbersome if you have a lot of contents to translate.
The [Translation Management](http://drupal.org/project/translation_management) or [Localization Client](http://drupal.org/project/l10n_client) modules would help on that regard.

You could get more ideas on this page: http://drupal.org/node/254214

Comment: I have installed the module of "Translation Management", however, it requires some of i18n modules to be enabled. So, Translation Management or Localization Client just like a client, and i18n is the core program?

Comment: Some of the modules provided in the "Translation Management" package use i18n, but if I recall correctly, some of them work with Locale-based modules.

Comment: "Localization Client" however is only for Locale-based modules.

Comment: If I may ask however, why don't you want to use i18n ? Or are you just inquiring about the alternatives ? Localization is a bit tricky in Drupal and i18n is somehow the lesser evil on the long term and it has quite a few handy modules to enhance it.

Comment: When I installed i18n module, I found that sometime the translation won't work, for example, when switching to other language, it return blank page, however, using other browser(not logged in as admin), it works.

Comment: Also, the menu can't be translated, e.g., for the same menu, created different language, but the menu disappeared when switching to other language.

Answer (score 2):

You can use other modules like:

https://www.drupal.org/project/gtranslate

https://www.drupal.org/project/gtrans

with these modules you don't need to add translated content manually for each languages.

But of course these modules uses 3rd party services to translate, so not efficient always.

So I suggest to use:
**Internationalization** with **Localization update**
Its work like charm, I am currently using it.

Answer (score 0):

And you can also use [entity translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) which allows you to do field level translation .You can translate a field also if required using this module

Answer (score 0):

Translation Management Tool (https://www.drupal.org/project/tmgmt) is a recent module.The Translation Management Tool (TMGMT) module provides a tool set for translating content from different sources. The translation can be done by people or translation services of all kinds. It builds on and uses existing language tools and data structures in Drupal and can be used in automated workflow scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

With i18n you have to install other modules like l10n_update, language dropdown, language icons, translation overview, variable. These are some of the module which make your multi language drop-down easy to use.